# Replace substring with ampersand

Tags: batch-file, replace, special-characters, ampersand

I can, according to [example](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.Replace) replace `,` with `m`,

```
@set str=abc,xyz
@echo %str:,=m%
```

However, I cannot replace it with ampersand,

```
@set str=abc,xyz
@echo %str:,=&%
```

Comment: `set "str=%str:,=&%"` <--- double quotes will work in this scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo %str:,=^&%
```

[you need to escape it](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)